# What is it called in math when more than one possibility can happen?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, terminology

I just want to ask, in probability, is there a word that describe a situation in which more than one possibility can happen as opposed to something that is jointly exhaustive or mutually exclusive where only a single outcome is permitted?

Thank you!

Comment: "not mutually exclusive"?

Comment: To be clear, *events* may be "not mutually exclusive" but *outcomes*, the elements of the sample space, **must** be mutually exclusive as per the axioms of probability.